# Creating extent indicator in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, extent-indicators

How do I put an inset map for my main map frame onto my map layout in QGIS 1.8 print composer?

I would like it to indicate the extent and location of the main map on a larger regional map. This something I am familiar with accomplishing in ArcMap but I have yet to discover if QGIS has an equivalent function. The indicator should show the extent of the data in the main frame in another data frame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called the "Overview Map".

The YouTube video called ["Tutorial 21 - Adding a Locus/Overview Map to a QGIS Print Composer"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uRds8DOwQc) shows how to add an overview map using what appears to be pre-2.0 tools.

There is also a new capability in the recent QGIS 2.0 release that is a more automated method of setting up an Overview map.  See [Print Composer - Overview](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#overviews) in the online QGIS User Guide, or it is located under Items/Map/Item Properties/Overview.

[image]