# how to add different data frames in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, qgis-plugins

How can I add different data frames in QGIS and show all data frames in single map like we add different data frames in ArcGIS and in single map we show these data frames?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle multiple map frames with different layers in one print layout?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45174/how-to-handle-multiple-map-frames-with-different-layers-in-one-print-layout) and/or [How to create an extent indicator in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72265/how-to-create-an-extent-indicator-in-qgis-1-8-print-composer)

Comment: thanx now i am near to my requirements :)